# Unreadable email sent with PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, html-email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I use PHPMail to send an email with pdf attachment. In most cases (about 90% of the times) the email gets send properly, but in some cases and I don't know in which cases, the email will show like this:

```
: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="b1_a3f9faae87f56d6f3d5b7325ee3fadf5"


--b1_a3f9faae87f56d6f3d5b7325ee3fadf5
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b2_a3f9faae87f56d6f3d5b7325ee3fadf5"

--b2_a3f9faae87f56d6f3d5b7325ee3fadf5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


Schakel HTML in om dit bericht goed te kunnen lezen




--b2_a3f9faae87f56d6f3d5b7325ee3fadf5
Content-Type: text/html; charset = "iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit





    <br><br>
                <table cellpadding='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width='130'><img src='http://www.emdr-lightbar.nl/images/psytec_mail.png' width='108' height='42' alt='Psytec'/></td>
                        <td><b>FACTUUR</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='border-top: 0px;border-bottom: 0px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed !important;' colspan='2'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='20'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td colspan='2'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>
                            <br><br>
                            Geachte mevrouw,<br><br>
                            Uw betaling is in goede orde ontvangen. Dank u wel. Uw factuur vindt u in de bijlage van deze email. 
                            <br><br>
                            Heeft u nog vragen? Neemt u dan contact op via de klantenservice</a>.
                            <br><br>
                            Uw ordernummer: 151<br><br>
                            Met vriendelijke groet,<br>
                            Fred Verschuur
                            <br><br><br>
                            </font>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='border-top: 0px;border-bottom: 0px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed !important;
        color: #757575;' colspan='2'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br>




--b2_a3f9faae87f56d6f3d5b7325ee3fadf5--
--b1_a3f9faae87f56d6f3d5b7325ee3fadf5
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="FA2015161.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FA2015161.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjQKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAy
IDAgUgovQW5ub3RzIFs8PC9UeXBlIC9Bbm5vdCAvU3VidHlwZSAvTGluayAvUmVjdCBbMjkwLjcz
IDI0MS44OSA0MDQuMjUgMjMxLjg5XSAvQm9yZGVyIFswIDAgMF0gL0EgPDwvUyAvVVJJIC9VUkkg
KG1haWx0bzprbGFudGVuc2VydmljZUBwc3l0ZWMubmwpPj4+Pl0KL0dyb3VwIDw8L1R5cGUgL0dy
b3VwIC9TIC9UcmFuc3BhcmVuY3kgL0NTIC9EZXZpY2VSR0I+PgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFI+Pgpl
```

I used this code:

```
<?PHP

function mailTo($to, $subject, $fromname, $message, $headers, $attachment, $attname) {
    global $mailer_user, $mailer_pass;
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail       = new PHPMailer();

    $body           = preg_replace('/\[\]/',"",$message);

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host             = "smpt.server.nl";

    $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
    $mail->Host             = "smpt.server.nl";
    $mail->Port             = 26;
    $mail->Username     = "username";
    $mail->Password     = "password";

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AltBody    = "Schakel HTML in om dit bericht goed te kunnen lezen";

    $mail->AddReplyTo('reply@domain.nl', 'Name');   
    $mail->SetFrom('klantenservice@domain.nl', 'Name');
    $mail->FromName     = $fromname;
    $mail->AddBCC('bcc@domain.nl');

    $mail->Subject      = $subject;
    $mail->Body     = $body;

    $mail->addCustomHeader($headers);

    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $address);

    if ($attachment) $mail->AddStringAttachment($attachment, $attname, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Chk yur html open close tags.

Comment: You are using a pretty old version of PHPMailer. [Update it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

Must be some kind of problem inside the mail headers.

```
$mail->addCustomHeader($headers);
```

What's inside `$headers`?

And what if you remove that line to test?

**Update**:

Your headers are almost certainly broken somewhere. For example, the shown email(body) starts with a single `:` on the whole line. So, somewhere before that there is a problem, probably caused by the contens of `$headers` - or `$headers` being empty or undefined as you say. And the remaining headers are pushed into the body of the mail, breaking all the `MIME` formatting.

So I would start by removing `$mail->addCustomHeader($headers);` to test if the problem is within `$headers`.

Comment: hmm, i see, $headers is not defined. Add some encoding parameters?

Comment: @FredV - It's a parameter in your function. If not needed, just remove the line `$mail->addCustomHeader($headers);`?

Comment: Thanks! Until now it seems fixed, but I keep testing!

Answer (score -1):

Use `isHTML()` after body. Its work for me in past.

```
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: @fredv mate did u try?

Comment: I tried, It worked, but in 90% of the cases it already worked, so I'll keep testing :-)

Comment: @Synchro: it has a basic difference, if u read my comments, use isHTML after the Body .... its very basic... but unfortunately this solution didnt help to OP. but i has a difference, if you think its a difference, than consider your downvoting... any way happy new year mate.

Comment: All `isHTML()` does is set the MIME type, and nothing reads that property until you send something, which happens after everything else. You do need to call it, but when you do so makes no difference. [Read the code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L725). Happy NY to you too!